# How can insert a background image in the bootsrap nav-pills using CSS? becausse i want it to become a image botton

Tags: html, css

here is the code

Marytown Place

Sta. Maria Bulacan

Comment: please update your link, it's not working

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab1">
       <a href="#" >
          <img src='img.png'>
       </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

i think this will help